# Borderlands 3 anointments

Tags: borderlands-3

I just found my first few items with anointments. And that got me wondering when they are activatable.

Can an anointment be activated if the item is in my inventory? Does it have to be equipped? For weapons, does it have to the currently selected weapon?

My guess would be that the item has to be equipped for a total of max 8 anointments active at once. Is that correct? Also are multiple same anointments stackable?

For example Zane has the anointment

> While SNTNL is active - 100% of dealt damage is added as cryo damage

on weapons. If I now equip 4 weapons with that anointment, do I now deal 400% of my damage as cryo damage?

Comment: my best guess is that anointment bonuses are only granted if the item is currently equiped(regarding armor/relics/etc) or used(weapons) because if not those boni would be seriously overpowered. also testing @ the weapons range eliminates guess work ;>